Json data not reaching to controller
<script>
    function makePayment() {
        const txRef = `shayonix-${new Date().getTime()}-${Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)}`;
        let price = document.getElementById("price").value;
        const user_email = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
        const username = document.getElementById("username").value;

        var store_id = document.getElementById("store_id").value;
        var plan_id = document.getElementById("plan_id").value;
        var start_date = document.getElementById("start_date").value;
        var end_date = document.getElementById("end_date").value;
        var status = 'active';

        var data = {
            store_id: store_id,
            plan_id: plan_id,
            start_date: start_date,
            end_date: end_date,
            status: status,
            price: price,
        };

        console.log(data);

        FlutterwaveCheckout({
            public_key: "FLWPUBK_TEST-7dfa27ed7558780e7b90be30246599b0-X",
            tx_ref: txRef,
            amount: price,
            currency: "TZS",
            payment_options: "card, ussd",
            callback: function(payment) {
                console.log(data);
                if (payment.status === "successful") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo admin_url('membership/insert_payment')?>",
                        data: $.param(data), 
                        success: function(response) {
                            document.getElementById("createForm").submit();
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            console.error("Error:", xhr.responseText);
                            document.querySelector("#payment-failed").style.display = 'block';
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    document.querySelector("#payment-failed").style.display = 'block';
                }
            },
            onclose: function() {
                console.log("Payment popup closed");
                document.querySelector("#payment-failed").style.display = 'block';
            },
            meta: {
                consumer_id: document.getElementById("user_id").value,
                consumer_mac: "92a3-912ba-1192a",
            },
            customer: {
                email: user_email,
                name: username,
            },
            customizations: {
                title: "Shayonix Membership POS",
                description: "Shayonix Membership POS Payment",
                logo: "",
            },
        });
    }
</script>

public function insert_payment() {

        $post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

        // Decode the JSON data
        $data = json_decode($post_data, true);
        
        $store_id = $this->input->post('store_id');
        $plan_id = $this->input->post('plan_id');
        $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
        $end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');
        $status = $this->input->post('status');
        $price = $this->input->post('price');
    
        $data = array(
            'store_id' => $store_id,
            'plan_id' => $plan_id,
            'start_date' => $start_date,
            'end_date' => $end_date,
            'status' => $status,
            'price' => $price,
        );

        var_dump($data);
    
        $insert = $this->db->insert('user_memberships', $data);
        $response = array('status' => $insert ? 'success' : 'error');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }


i am that on successful payment the data should enter in the database and the data is displaying in the console tab but its not showing in the controller when i redirect to the controller the data is showing null

done i have rectified that mistake

The issue you're encountering seems to stem from how the data is being sent from your JavaScript code to your controller. Specifically, the $.param(data) method in jQuery encodes the data as a query string, not JSON. This might be causing problems when trying to retrieve the data on the server side, especially if you are expecting JSON.
Here's how you can ensure the data is sent as JSON and processed correctly on the server side:

Update the AJAX request to send JSON data:
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo admin_url('membership/insert_payment')?>",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response) {
        document.getElementById("createForm").submit();
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error("Error:", xhr.responseText);
        document.querySelector("#payment-failed").style.display = 'block';
    }
});


Adjust the server-side code to read JSON input:
In your PHP controller, make sure to decode the JSON input properly:
public function insert_payment() {
    $post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $data = json_decode($post_data, true);

    $store_id = $data['store_id'];
    $plan_id = $data['plan_id'];
    $start_date = $data['start_date'];
    $end_date = $data['end_date'];
    $status = $data['status'];
    $price = $data['price'];

    $data = array(
        'store_id' => $store_id,
        'plan_id' => $plan_id,
        'start_date' => $start_date,
        'end_date' => $end_date,
        'status' => $status,
        'price' => $price,
    );

    // Insert the data into the database
    $insert = $this->db->insert('user_memberships', $data);
    $response = array('status' => $insert ? 'success' : 'error');
    echo json_encode($response);
}



By ensuring the data is sent as JSON and decoded properly on the server side, you should be able to avoid issues with data not reaching your controller correctly.
Additional Notes:

Make sure to handle potential JSON parsing errors both on the client and server sides.
Ensure that your server is configured to accept JSON content type by verifying server settings and any middleware (if using frameworks like CodeIgniter or Laravel).
You may also want to log the raw POST data and the decoded data to debug any issues further.


Did AI write that answer? fyi: Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?
